# How to create and load module policy in SElinux

Tags: module, policy, selinux

I'm attempting to create and load a new module policy for SeLinux on Redhat Enterprise Linux 7. The .te file would be  :

```
module myapp 1.0.0

type myapp_t;
type myapp_exec_t;
domain_type(myapp_t)
domain_entry_file(myapp_t, myapp_exec_t) 

type myapp_log_t;
logging_log_file(myapp_log_t)

allow myapp_t myapp_log_t:file { read };
```

but I don't know how to make and load this!
I tried this for generating type enforcement file using audit2allow :

```
grep setsebool /var/log/audit/audit.log  | audit2allow -M myapp
```

I got this :

> Nothing to do

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: You need to compile the policy source, this will give you a .pp file that can be loaded by semodule. I can't say exactly for REHL but the gentoo guide is quite clear and generally compatible, at least for the basic process, check [this](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SELinux/Tutorials/Creating_your_own_policy_module_file) out and let me know!

Answer (score 0):

After your create .te file

**Compile:**

We can easily generate .pp file, using

`make -f /usr/share/selinux/devel/Makefile mydaemon.pp`

*Note: .pp file name should be same as .te filename

eg: mydaemon.te than .pp file name should be mydaemon.pp*

**Install:**

Now after .pp file is generated its time to install it

To install, use
`semodule -i mydaemon.pp`

**Verify:**

To verify if module is installed

`semodule -l | grep mydaemon`